# how to find out method is executed?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, queue, event-bus

Assume that we have below method which will be called in differnt times, for example 10 times :

```
EventBus.getDefault().post(Id_of_Media_Group);
```

and receiver method in another class will be like below method in a sequentially way ( **because of using ThreadNode.MAIN_ORDERED** ) :

```
    @Subscribe(threadMode = ThreadMode.MAIN_ORDERED)
    public void refreshList(ExampleClass example) {
    // doing a fairly heavy duty
}
```

this means that will be done using a queue(of callings), and every Queue's element(calling function) may take a few time to finish, my question is that, how Can I understand when every job or all these jobs will be finished using Listener?
my Listener must be in former method class.

Answer (score 0):

Use a AtomicInteger in your receiver method and increment it when ever it gets called
At the end you can check that atomic to see how many times it's been called

Comment: No, this Listener should be in sender method side, I mean when the JOB in receiver side is done ,sender should be noticed instantly

Comment: please paste a sample code or elaborate more on that

Answer (score 0):

> well that is so simple make Logs in every job , and see it in Logcat if your Log execute or not. here is the Example, Log.d("checking the jobs","jobs 1 is done");